# How to downgrade USB 3.0 to USB 2.0?

Tags: usb, drivers

I have USB 2.0 device when I plugged this device into the USB 3.0 port of my system then system gets hanged, after researching many of the solutions says that you can downgrade USB 3.0 to USB 2.0. But I didn't get any specific documentation for related to downgrading process.

How can I downgrade USB 3.0 to USB 2.0. I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Plug the device into a USB 2.0 hub.

Comment: BTW, please, provide links of where you read that you can "downgrade USB 3.0 to USB 2.0". I would like to have a talk with them.

Comment: I'm not aware of any method to downgrade the ports. The USB2 and USB3 is built into the ports themselves. See my A about detecting the port type: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112143/detect-which-usb-slot-is-2-0-or-3-0/112152#112152

Comment: @sim So we didn't convert/downgrade USB 3.0 to USB 2.0. and also there shouldn't be any software/driver that convert them.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

USB 2.0 or 3.0 is a hardware specification and has little to do with the OS. There's no way to downgrade (or upgrade) an specific USB version. What you can do is plugging your device in a 2.0 hub. USB 3.0 is totally backwards compatible with 2.0 and 1.1 devices, but some glichs can appear in the kernel implementation of the specification, in such cases is better to report a bug to your distribution bugtracker, in the case of Ubuntu, https://launchpad.net